# Rename headers of several multifasta files in bioinformation job

Tags: awk, sed

I have the 1.files like this:

```
>YP_008856774.1 
MHGTRTSAGWSTQPGKFDVLNLRMTFESSSAYQIPDLQPTEFIPTSLAAWNMPRHREYAAVSGGALHFFLDDYRFETVWS
>YP_008856775.1
MGGRGGGGGPGPGTGAKNKKAGGGSAGGLGGGGGSGGSSGGGGKGTGTTGTGGVQNGSGGGGNGAGGGSSNTTKPVEQYE
>YP_008856776.1 
MQPPIEPVDPPTGDVSPYPNDLLILGGNRWLTITGRILHTPFGDQVELKPNTVKFWEAAAMRGQGKTLSELIV
>YP_008856777.1 
MTWAGSRRRDELPPDWELKYRLPVLSAANWLCEVNGPGCVRAATDVDHKKRGNDHSRSNLQAICRVCHGRKSAAEGVARR
```

I want to rename each tag (eg.>YP_008856776.1) like this:

```
>YP008856_1
MHGTRTSAGWSTQPGKFDVLNLRMTFESSSAYQIPDLQPTEFIPTSLAAWNMPRHREYAAVSGGALHFFLDDYRFETVWS
>YP008856_2
MGGRGGGGGPGPGTGAKNKKAGGGSAGGLGGGGGSGGSSGGGGKGTGTTGTGGVQNGSGGGGNGAGGGSSNTTKPVEQYE
>YP008856_3
MQPPIEPVDPPTGDVSPYPNDLLILGGNRWLTITGRILHTPFGDQVELKPNTVKFWEAAAMRGQGKTLSELIV
>YP008856_4
MTWAGSRRRDELPPDWELKYRLPVLSAANWLCEVNGPGCVRAATDVDHKKRGNDHSRSNLQAICRVCHGRKSAAEGVARR
```

Firstly, I used `sed -i "s/\_//g" 1.file` to delete `\_`. Or I should delete the last four characters of the header, and then add the `_` and "order number"? In short, I want to rename the tag after the `>`; The first step is
replace the `_`;And then delete the last four characters of each tag, after that, add `_` after each tag, finally, add sequential numbers after each tag.(eg.>YP_008856774.1 to >YP008856774.1 to >YP008856 to >YP008856_ to >YP008856_1). I can't achieve it with my ability for now. Can you help me with the trouble? Thanks.

Comment: Regarding `sed -i "s/_//g" 1.file` - 1) you only have 1 `_` on each line so adding a `g` at the end of your command to remove multiple `_`s is misleading at best. 2) All strings and scripts should be inside single quotes unless you **need** double quotes or no quotes - see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and all previous answers you got. 3) Don't add `-i` to any sed script in any question as it trashes your input in failure cases, add `-i` yourself later if you like once you have a working solution that produces the desired output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you want us to do. If you need us to delete the last four characters before the `.` in each header, _tell us_. Also, remember that people here are not bioinformaticians and have no idea what "fasta" or "multi-fasta" mean and so they won't know what a "header" is. The more detail you give, the better your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: For example, I just deleted my answer because I didn't notice that you want to increment the number. That is because you didn't say it anywhere. Please don't make us waste our time and yours by forcing us to guess what you need. You need to explain it in the question.

Comment: So sorry for wasting your time, I've changed my question, not very familiar with it since I'm freshman to the community, I'll change my mistake immediately. Thanks for your help.@terdon @Ed Morton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using GNU `awk`

```
$ awk -F_ 'BEGIN {c=1} /^>/{match($2,/(.{6}).*/,a); $2=a[1] FS c++}1' OFS="" input_file
>YP008856_1
MHGTRTSAGWSTQPGKFDVLNLRMTFESSSAYQIPDLQPTEFIPTSLAAWNMPRHREYAAVSGGALHFFLDDYRFETVWS
>YP008856_2
MGGRGGGGGPGPGTGAKNKKAGGGSAGGLGGGGGSGGSSGGGGKGTGTTGTGGVQNGSGGGGNGAGGGSSNTTKPVEQYE
>YP008856_3
MQPPIEPVDPPTGDVSPYPNDLLILGGNRWLTITGRILHTPFGDQVELKPNTVKFWEAAAMRGQGKTLSELIV
>YP008856_4
MTWAGSRRRDELPPDWELKYRLPVLSAANWLCEVNGPGCVRAATDVDHKKRGNDHSRSNLQAICRVCHGRKSAAEGVARR
```

Comment: It'd be nice if you could share the reason you downvoted me @Kusalananda.

Comment: I can see that someone might have downvoted you due to missing an explanation of the non-trivial `awk` code, or the lack of assumptions about the input.  My critique would be about what would happen if the labels are not all the same. You code would then just continue using the same counter, `c`, for all of them.  You also seem to be using GNU `awk` specifically?

Comment: @Kusalananda I appreciate you providing the reason. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '/>/{$0=substr($0,1,3) substr($0,5,6) "_" (++c)} 1' file
>YP008856_1
MHGTRTSAGWSTQPGKFDVLNLRMTFESSSAYQIPDLQPTEFIPTSLAAWNMPRHREYAAVSGGALHFFLDDYRFETVWS
>YP008856_2
MGGRGGGGGPGPGTGAKNKKAGGGSAGGLGGGGGSGGSSGGGGKGTGTTGTGGVQNGSGGGGNGAGGGSSNTTKPVEQYE
>YP008856_3
MQPPIEPVDPPTGDVSPYPNDLLILGGNRWLTITGRILHTPFGDQVELKPNTVKFWEAAAMRGQGKTLSELIV
>YP008856_4
MTWAGSRRRDELPPDWELKYRLPVLSAANWLCEVNGPGCVRAATDVDHKKRGNDHSRSNLQAICRVCHGRKSAAEGVARR
```

Answer (score 1):

```bash
$ awk '/^>/ { tag = substr($0,1,3) substr($0,5,6); $0 = sprintf("%s_%d", tag, ++count[tag]) }; 1' file
>YP008856_1
MHGTRTSAGWSTQPGKFDVLNLRMTFESSSAYQIPDLQPTEFIPTSLAAWNMPRHREYAAVSGGALHFFLDDYRFETVWS
>YP008856_2
MGGRGGGGGPGPGTGAKNKKAGGGSAGGLGGGGGSGGSSGGGGKGTGTTGTGGVQNGSGGGGNGAGGGSSNTTKPVEQYE
>YP008856_3
MQPPIEPVDPPTGDVSPYPNDLLILGGNRWLTITGRILHTPFGDQVELKPNTVKFWEAAAMRGQGKTLSELIV
>YP008856_4
MTWAGSRRRDELPPDWELKYRLPVLSAANWLCEVNGPGCVRAATDVDHKKRGNDHSRSNLQAICRVCHGRKSAAEGVARR
```

The above `awk` command would rewrite each header line by using the specific parts (characters 1 through to 3, and 5 through to 10, skipping the `_` at position 4) of the original header line as the tag. A counter is maintained for each unique tag.

This assumes that the original identifiers are always on the form `XX_NNNNNN` followed by whatever other text (which is ignored).

You could also use

```bash
awk '/^>/ { sub(/_/, ""); sub(/...\..*/, ""); tag = $0; $0 = sprintf("%s_%d", tag, ++count[tag]) }; 1' file
```

This would be slightly more dynamic in that it creates the tag from what's left of the original identifier after removing an underscore and anything after (and including) a set of three characters and a dot.

Comment: I appreciate you providing excellent codes, so kind of you. @Kusalananda

Answer (score -3):

I get it finally, but must use `seqkit` software.

```
for i in `cat id`; do 
    echo ${i%*${i:(-8)}} | sed "s/\_//g" > tmp
    for j in `cat tmp`; do 
        echo $j
        echo -e ">abc\nACTG\n>123\nATTT" |  seqkit replace -p ".+" -r "$j_{nr}" --nr-width 5 $i > $i.new.gz
        less -S $i.new.gz | sed 's/>/\>'"${j}"_'/g' | sed 's/00//g'> $i.fa
    done
done
```

Comment: That code appears to be doing things that are unrelated to your question and contains multiple bad practices and anti-patterns. You should copy/paste it into http://shellcheck.net to learn about **some** (but not all) of them. Also please read [my first comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/711490/rename-headers-of-several-multifasta-files-in-bioinformation-job/711598#comment1347261_711490) for other issues with your `sed "s/\_//g"` sed script specifically and you don't need to escape `_` in a regexp, it's not a metachar.